# checking TimeStamp for LocalStorage record

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I have got a div with dynamic content:

```
<div id="news">test</div>
```

And want to add its content to LocalStorage for 50 sec to prevent new requests to the server and if it is older than 50 sec then remove it and set a new content. My jQuery is:

```
 $(function(){
 function now() {return+new Date}
 var db = window.db = {
  get  : function(key) {
    var entry = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key)||"0");
    if (!entry) return null;
    if (entry.ttl && entry.ttl + entry.now < now()) {
        localStorage.removeItem(key);
        return null;
    }
    return entry.value;
},
set : function( key, value, ttl ) {
    localStorage.setItem( key, JSON.stringify({
        ttl   : ttl || 0,
        now   : now(),
        value : value
    }) );
  }
 };
 });

 $(function() {
 // Set Value with TTL of 50 Seconds using Milliseconds.
 db.set( "homeNews", $("#news").html(), 50000 );
 });

 $(function() {
 var contentsOfNews = db.get("homeNews");
 $("#news").html(contentsOfNews);
 });
```

The issue is: it is adding the content to the LocalStorage every load but should check timestamp and if the content was added more than 50 sec then rewrite this LocalStorage data. If less than 50 sec than just do nothing. Thank you for your help.

Please feel free to edit the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KQmky/1/

Thanks a million

Comment: Use [setTimeout()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) function

Comment: Thank you Pavlo, sorry for being stupid but can you please help with this in my jsfiddle? Thank you in advance

Comment: `setTimeout(function(){ db.set( "homeNews", $("#news").html(), 50000 ); }, 50000);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a check in the set function, to see if the value exists, and check its ttl there too

Something like this should suffice:

```
set : function( key, value, ttl ) {
    var entry = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key)||"0");

    if (!entry || (entry.ttl && entry.ttl + entry.now < now())) { 
        //set the new value in local storage 
    }
}
```

That way if there is no entry then set it to save, or if there is an entry but its ttl has passed then it will overwrite it

Comment: Thank you user2355891, can you please implement your code to my jsFiddle? Your help is really appreciated.

Comment: Thank but if you can test it by changing the content of the first div you can see that it still changin' the localstorage everytime